# how to update xml data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have below table structure

ID int

xmlData xml

I want data in the xml column (xmlData) to updated with new value based on below condition. Below is the sample data in xml column.

```
<customer>
  <name display="CName">abc</name>
  <customerId display="CID">123</customerId>
</customer>
```

some rows in my table may not have customerId xml  tag , i want to identity those and need to update the xml tag with customerId

Please suggest , how i can do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [modify() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with [insert (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
update YourTable
set xmlData.modify('insert <customerId display="CID">123</customerId> 
                    into customer[1]')
where xmlData.exist('/customer/customerId') = 0
```

Use [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in the where clause so you only update the rows that does not have a `customerId` node.

Comment: Thank you I have few other cases .Please suggest for below case

Comment: How to provide dynamic date for "CID"                               How to check if display="CID"  attribute exists , if not exists i have to add that attribute as well

Comment: @user1814841 Sorry, I  don't fully understand what you want. Do you mean that you want a dynamic value for `display` when you say `CID`? What do you mean by "CID exists"? What should happen if `display` has another value than the dynamically provided value? Should `display` be added if the attribute `display` is missing? Should the value in `display` be update if it already exist? Please do not answer these questions in a comment. Instead you should update your question to make the question clearer.

Comment: apologies for the confusion, From the above query(query which you provided) how I can replace all rows if the inner value of customerId =123 ,

Comment: @user1814841 I still don't get it. Your question is about when the `customerId` node is missing. How can it have a value of `123` if it is missing?

Comment: when i execute the above query which you provided , it will update all nodes with customerId , after this i want another query to update customerId to new value , i wanted some thing like below                                                          UPDATE Customer
SET xmlData.modify('replace value of (/customer/customerId[1]/text())[1]
        with ( cast(@id1 as char(10)) ) ')